# Create a Listener to Stop a Method Until Custom Callback Completes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.android, async-await, delegates

I would like to stop a method until a custom delegate provides a callback from one method to a listener in another in Xamarin.Android, but I am having a lot of trouble understanding the implementation of such a listener.

I have only tried to understand how this could be done, but I'm stuck on how the delegate would be constructed and called.

Let's say that I want this MainActivity method to stop

```
    public async override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
    {
           base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

           //how can I create a listener to stop this method until callback from OnPause?
           //await a delegate task?

    }
```

and await another method inside a Fragment:

```
    public override void OnResume()
    {
         base.OnResume();

         //I'd like to implement a delegate here to notify the OnWindowFocusChanged that OnResume method has been invoked
         //what would be the construction of such?
    }
```

How could I do that?

From my research, I believe I would need to create a delegate task, and then await it's return in OnWindowFocusChanged.  However, I am confused about the implementation of such a solution.  If anyone could provide even a very basic pseudo-code example, it would help me out a lot.

EDIT: I changed OnPause to OnResume because that's more useful for understanding what I'm trying to do.  The below answer references OnPause, but those two are extremely similar methods anyway.

Here is an example that *almost* does what I'm trying to do; except instead of starting my method when OnResume is invoked, OnWindowFocusChanged stops for 10000ms.  So basically, I'd like to replace the timer with a custom delegate (similar to an event) task that returns when Fragment.OnResume is invoked.

```
    public async override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
    {
         base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

         //we won't pass this line for 10000ms; how to replace with Task return?
         await WaitHere();
    }


    async Task WaitHere()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Task.Run` method like:

```
await Task.Run(() => OnPause());
```

This would basically create a new thread or use the one you are on and schedule everything after this line as a continuation. So yes, the method would kinda stop, but unless you are on some GUI thread (not to block) or you run some IO task this is unnecessary.

I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve, but you might try to create new OnPauseAsync method that would return Task to get some result from the method when it finishes. This way you would get sequential like mechanism that doesn't block.

If you want to run those methods truly in parallel, but stop execution of `OnWindowFocusChanged` unitl something hapens in `OnPause` you should use bare Threads and some synchronization primitives like Mutex or Barrier. Then you would be able to make "main" thread wait until something happens (but it would block! beware). About those fellas you can read more here : [LINK_WITH_FOCUS_ON_BARRIER](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_Barrier_Class)

I am not really sure I got your intentions right, but I hope it helps somehow in the end.

To review:

- if you just want to wait for the completion of OnPause and it does only CPU heavy things and you are not on UI thread - do not do anything as there is no profit in using threads etc.
- if onPause does some IO heavy things you can use:

  - Tasks - potentially executed on one thread and doesn't block, control is returned to `OnWindowFocusChanged` AFTER `onPause` finishes completely.
  - Threads - if you want to run some parallel (two threads guaranteed) computations and wait for `onPause` to signal AT SOME POINT of execution to its caller that it might proceed, you can use e.g Barrier - but beware as this is the most complex solution from programmers perspective and it blocks if you are on UI thread.

Comment: to clarify a bit about my intent for this, if I can pause the OnWindowFocusChanged method, my WebView audio will continue playing in the background while the user does other things.  I want to use await to pause it until Fragment.OnResume is invoked.  In my example I used OnPause, but the implementation should be similar, regardless.

Comment: thanks for the response; that is definitely helpful.  I don't care if the UI is blocked by the await because my app will be in background state.

Comment: I tried await Task.Run(() => _fm1.OnResume()); and my OnWindowFocusChanged method does not wait for OnResume to be invoked.  The method just blows past that line.  If I do something like await WaitHere();

         async Task WaitHere()
         {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
         }

then my app keeps playing audio for 10000ms in the background ... i'd like a similar method that stops the OnWindowFocusChanged method until a custom delegate is called by OnResume

Comment: @hexagod Additional context :D So, there is a music playing somewhere and when OnWindowFocusChanged is invoked you want to stop it untill user clicks some button that invokes OnResume? Please correct me if I am wrong and provide broader context of what you want to do, not how to implement your solution. This might by XY problem

Comment: I want my WebView video to continue playing when the app is in background state.  I figured out that if I can suspend OnWindowFocusChanged or OnPause the WebView audio continues playing in background.  I chose to suspend OnWindowFocusChanged because OnResume and OnPause are invoked *before* OnWindowFocusChanged ... therefore, if I override OnWindowFocusChanged with an async modifier I can wait until OnResume is invoked by the app again then resume the UI.  Here's my full project https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav